# How to return to the prompt message if the user enters empty value and hits ok?

Tags: javascript, function, prompt

How can I get the prompt to detect the null value in javascript?

I tried this but entering ok will return a "Hello" instead of "Enter again".

```js
function myprompt() {
  var a = prompt("Enter your name", "abc");
  if (a != null) {
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "Hello " + a;
  } else if (a == "") {
    document.write("Enter again");
  } else {
    document.write("BYE...")
  }
}
myprompt()
```

```html
<p id="para"></p>
```

I'm making a JavaScript project and I want to alert when the user enters nothing in the prompt

What it's supposed to do:

1. input any name or string from the user
2. prompt for the name of the user
3. alert the message enter again when the user enters a null value
4. alert the message bye when the user cancels the prompt

But when I test it and enter nothing it says hello - why?

Comment: `null` is only returned if the user clicks 'cancel', otherwise an empty string is returned, which is not equal to null, triggering your fist condition.

Comment: the empty string is not equal - not even "loose equal" in JS - to `null`. So it's going to hit your first condition before the one that specifically checks for the empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

> When the user clicks the OK button, text entered in the input field is returned. If the user clicks OK without entering any text, an empty string is returned. If the user clicks the Cancel button, this function returns null.

```js
function myPrompt() {
    var a = prompt("Enter your name", "John Doe");
    if (a == null) {
        document.write("User have cancelled the prompt!");
    } else if (a == "") {
        document.write("User haven't entered anything and clicked OK");
    } else {
        document.write("User have entered a valid text")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myprompt() {
  const a = prompt("Enter your name", "abc");
  if (a === null) {
    console.log("canceled");
    document.write("BYE...");
  } else if (a === "") {
    console.log("enter again");
    document.write("Enter again");
  } else {
    console.log("Hello " + a);
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "Hello " + a;
  }
}
```

You used double `==` but its better to use `===`.
And `var` is also not recommended

Comment: None of your recommendations solve the issue, and are more of a semantic discussion. Sometimes `==` _is_ useful, unless you have a back-end type-based background.

Answer (score 0):

`a != null` is evaluating before `a == ""`. `a == ""` means a is not null, so you will never reach that part of the if condition. You need to invert your conditions.

start with a null check, then empty string, then non-empty string, not the other way around.

```js
function myprompt() {
  var a = prompt("Enter your name", "abc");
  if (a == null) {
    document.write("BYE...");
  } else if (a == "") {
    document.write("Enter again");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "Hello " + a;
  }
}
myprompt()
```

```html
<p id="para"></p>
```